# Java unsigned - remove sign bit

Tags: java, converters, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I have this function:

```
public static final int UNSIGN(short b){

    return (b & 0xFFFF);
}
```

The intent here is to use the value in 'b' as if it were positive, by this I mean as if it were an unsigned int, capable of holding 65536 values. However, it doesn't work. For example:

If 'b == -122' the function returns '65414'.

I also tried this way:

```
public static final int UNSIGN(short b){

    return (b & 0xFF);
}
```

But that would return me '48' if 'b == 304'.

I'm really lost here, hope someone can help out.

Comment: `-122` is not positive so what value did you expect the function to return?

Answer (score 2):

> The intent here is to use the value in 'b' as if it were positive.

Do you mean you want to find the absolute value of `b`? That would be [`Math.abs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29).

But your code *is* treating `b` as if it were an unsigned short. When `b` is -122, the bits will be

```
1111111110000110
```

... which is 65414 when viewed as an unsigned value.

(122 is 0000000001111010, so to negate it you reduce the value by 1 and flip all the bits.)

Comment: ok I guess I did not explain myself very well. I do not want the absolute value, I want the positive value for the 16bits. basically I want the value as if it were unsigned short.

Comment: @sazr: And that's exactly what it's giving you. What value did you *want* it to give you for b == -122?

Comment: why do you expect that value?

Comment: @Arian because if java had unsigned bytes, that would be what the value would be for a byte with value -122.

Comment: Yes, but you're not working with bytes.  You're working with shorts.  And treating the bits of `(short) -122` as unsigned gets you, correctly, 65414.

Comment: Exactly. Furthermore, in your question you write that you expect some result for `b=304`. So apparently, you don't want bytes either. Maybe you should take a step back and think about what you actually want, because if Jon Skeet's answer isn't right, the question is wrong.

Comment: @Arian It is really hard to explain without giving lots of context and a few lines of code... but I'll try anyway: the value that the function UNSIGN receives, is always in [0,255]. Because we dont have unsigneds in Java, that is seen as something in [-127,127]. The case where it takes a value greater than 255, is a very specific case, one that I can easily catch and avoid the function call to UNSIGN. Hope this helps clarifying it, sorry.

Comment: @sazr: So you don't want the value as if it were an unsigned `short`, you want the value as if it were an unsigned `byte`, except in the case where the value is positive, in which case it should be treated as a `short`? (Look at your example of 304, which falls outside your range of [0, 255].) Fundamentally your question is still *very* unclear.

Comment: If the parameter is always in [0;255], you have already given the correct answer in your question: `return (b & 0xFF);`. Just make sure you never call it with something else. (Also, if your question is hard to explain, what kind of answers do you expect when you give almost no explanation at all?)